# Equivalence of Schatten and spectral norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'd like some help showing the equivalence of these two norms when $p = \log n$.

Recall the [$p$-th Schatten norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) of a linear operator $A$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. In the particular case of $p = \log(n)$, Schatten norm should be equivalent to the spectral norm, [see last line on p.18](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf). Moreover, $\| A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}} \leq \| A \|$.

On the other hand, consider an example of an operator on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

Obviously, $\| A \| = 3$. However when $p = \log(3)$, the corresponding Schatten's norm is

$$ \| A \|_{C^{3}_{\log 3}} = \left( 1^{\log 3} + 2^{\log 3} + 3^{\log 3}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log 3}} \approx 5.48 $$

implying that $\| A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}} > \| A \|$.

Am I doing something wrong without realizing it? I'm confused here.
I'd like to show the equivalence of two norms but I'm stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In finite dimensional vector space all norms are equivalent, and you can use a [general theorem](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math561_spring2011/norm_equiv.pdf) to prove your assertion, otherwise
$$
\lVert A \rVert_{C^n_p} := \left(\sum_1^n s_i(A)^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \\
\left(n \cdot\sup_i\{s_i(A)^p\}\right)^{1/p} = n^{1/p} \cdot \sup_i\{s_i(A)\} = n^{1/p} \cdot \lVert A \rVert
$$
and
$$
\lVert A \rVert := \sup_i \{s_i(A)\} = \left(\sup_i\{s_i(A)^p\}\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\sum_1^n s_i(A)^p\right)^{1/p} = \lVert A \rVert_{C^n_p}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cleared some things up. However, could you confirm that the inequality stated in the paper I refered to, i.e. $\| A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}} \leq \| A \| \leq e\|A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}}$ is actually false? It certainly seems so given my "counter-example". Adapting it from the proof, the correct one should look like $$\|A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}} \leq e\|A\| \leq n\|A\|_{C^{n}_{\log n}}$$ which is obtained setting $p = \log n$.

Comment: To add to my comment, I now guess that the inequalities can be sharpened. It seems that in all cases $\|A\| \leq \| A \|_{C^{n}_{p}}$ for $p \geq 1$ so that we have $\| A \|_{C^{n}_{p}} \leq e\|A\| \leq e\| A \|_{C^{n}_{p}}$. I guess that the paper missed an $e$ somewhere.

Comment: @johnny I confirm that the inequality stated in the paper is false and, as you suggested, I sharpened the second inequality in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The article "Random Vectors in the Isotropic Position" by M. Rudelson also has the inequality that has the same 'wrong' form as that you mentioned.